# Is my CTR with Google Admob too high?

Tags: android, admob

I have implemented google admob ads in my android apps.
It's ordinary banner + interstitial.

Banners are not refreshing automatically.

So in last days I have 26k impressions and 240 clicks.
It means CTR is around 0.95% (and earnings are 1$ per 1k impressions).

Please, tell me, is it too high?

I've never clicked on ads and placed ads correctly, but I'm worried about invalid clicks.

Which CTR is normal?

Answer (score 0):

Anton this is totally normal CTR rate [Look at this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-CTR-for-mobile-ads)
Its actually a bit low then average you dont need to worry. also notice that usually interstitial ctr is higher then banners